# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know that this question has been asked a lot, but nothing I've seen so far worked.

I have a wp in root, running from subdirectory (I like things clean). I also a few subdomains running from subdirectories in root (eg. public_html/sample.com). I get the error only on subdomains that are pure HTML and CSS. They don't use any platform.

Here's my .htaccess from root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Things I've tried:

1) Comment out all RewriteRule - solves the problem, but then my wp doesn't work. It gives 404 error when I go to any posts or pages.

2) Changed the .htaccess to the following (courtesy of Scott Yang):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

but that didn't change anything.

3) I also tried commenting out and pasting new code from other questions, quite on random, but it's the same story.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Are there any other rules?

Comment: There is one concerning fonts, I had a problem that fonts wouldn't load due to SSL or something, don't remember exactly what's there, but I know that it makes no difference to the error. It was the first thing to go when I realised I had this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.

In the root directory for the subdomain, in the .htaccess add the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewrite Rule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This is how you can get rid of .php from the end of URL. 
Replace .php with .html and it also gets rid of .html

For some reason, this fixes the problem.

Cheers

EDIT:

This solved the problem, but it didn't remove the .html from the URL. Below worked perfectly

```
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Cheers